# Freeze the coloumn in dhtmlxgrid is not working when table converted into DhtmlxGrid

Tags: dhtmlx

I converted the table into DhtmlxGrid but while applying the freezing is not working for me.kindly advise on this

```
  <table imgpath="../codebase/imgs/" style="width:400px" id="gridTable" name="gridTable" onbeforeinit="initGrid()">
    ...
    </table>


    <script>

    table = new dhtmlXGridFromTable("gridTable");

    function initGrid(){

    gridTable.splitAt(10);

    }

</script>
```

Comment: The 'frozen column' feature is available in the PRO version only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that grid.splitAt() needs to be called after the grid is initialized.